# How to precise weight paint

Tags: weight-painting

I have a model and I want to copy the weight paint from the previous model. However, I want to know how did they managed to be that precise with the weight painting as I also don't wanna use vertex group transfer. (Also Because I tried and it didn't work.)

What I'm trying to get:

[image]

What I got so far:

[image]

Comment: Straight lines between vertices helps a bit https://imgur.com/a/BwExuyr

Comment: Yeah, I would avoid bendy vertices in the future unless needed. But this model (Above) is just a high vert count, Not bendy verts. But thanks for the heads up regardless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have to be aware that our "precision" is limited by our vertex count; only vertices have weights, so between our vertices, we cannot set any weights, and Blender is just showing us the interpolated values between that face's vertices.

After that, we have a few options beyond "drag a brush around" (which is our worst option, and one that I barely ever use for actual bone weights.)

[image]

Here, look at the properties panel.  I've selected a vertex group, a particular weight value on the weight slider, and a loop of vertices.  When I click "assign", all of those vertices are assigned that value.  You can see, this is very precise.  This can be done in edit mode as easily as in weight paint mode, and that's usually where I'd be doing it, but then you couldn't see the colors.

[image]

Here's another way, which I've done diagonally-- that's probably not good, in a real life situation it suggests topo that doesn't work with the bones-- but it demonstrates things about the technique.  Here, look especially at the falloff curve on the sidebar.  I've edited this curve to so it goes low, to high, to low, which is different that all the base curves; then, rather than dabbing paint, I drew a linear gradient over the mesh.  You can find this on the toolbar; I use alt-click-drag shortcut instead.  (We could do something similar by adding a gradient, and subtracting a gradient, but it won't ever be *quite* as perfect-- we'll never draw the exact same line for the two gradients.)

We could also use modifiers to control weights precisely.  We might use vertex weight proximity or geometry nodes modifiers to get the exact weights we want; these can be applied to write their effect into the weights.  But another option is to use a data transfer modifier to paint weights from another object:

[image]

This tank top has no weights of its own, not originally; instead, it's acquiring its weights from the plane, where I've just assigned 4 vertices.  These weights interpolate linearly (smoothly, precisely) over the plane's triangles, and are then copied by the tank top.  I can even do this live if I need to, so that I can adjust weights by adjusting the plane-- not just by adjusting its weights, but adjusting the positions of its vertices as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, This really helped me out ALOT. now I don't have to spend hours trying to get a good weight paint for each bone!